# Not able to edit sharepoint list in infopath inside windows server 2012r2

Tags: list, infopath, windows-server

I am able to edit the sharepoint list form in my local machine using infopath desinger 2013. But if I try to edit the same inside server, windows server 2012R2, then it is giving, **Infopath cannot generate a form template for the sharepoint list**

[image]

Do I need to activate any windows/server feature or need to modify any settings inside server? 
I am not able to connect sharepoint site as network drive also. It is saying cannot find find.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the below feature is enabled in Site Collection features.

**"SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features"**

Comment: Thats why I am saying I able to edit in my local machine. Problem is only in server. Feature was activated already.